Use fdupes to compare two directories
Is it possible to use fdupes to compare the contents of two directories (dir1 and dir2), identify files in dir2 that are present in dir1, and delete those duplicates files from dir2?
Alternatively, since the directories are relatively small and could be moved into a single parent directory (e.g., dir_parent/dir1 and dir_parent/dir2), is there a way to guarantee the files in dir_parent/dir1 are identified as the "first" copy and the files in dir_parent/dir2 are identified as the "second" copy?
If I missed a previous version of this question, please feel free to mark this version as "duplicate" :-D

This util fdupes use MD5 hash which is counted as not very reliable (collisions). Maybe you can create small script which use sha1 (or even sha256) and compare the hashes.
